# Simple c# encryption program Issues

Tags: c#

I keep getting An unhandled exception of type
'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException Additional

information: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.

i have tried setting the arrays to a fixed amout but i keep getting the same issue

PROGRAM BELOW

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace encryptionApp
{
    class Program
    {

        //function to chage substring to number
        public static int ToNumber(string subString)
        {
            int returnInt;

            // string to number convestion switch
            switch (subString)
            {
                case "A":

                    returnInt = 1;
                    return returnInt;

                case "B":

                    returnInt = 2;
                    return returnInt;

                case "C":

                    returnInt = 3;
                    return returnInt;

                case "D":

                    returnInt = 4;
                    return returnInt;

                case "E":

                    returnInt = 5;
                    return returnInt;

                case "F":

                    returnInt = 6;
                    return returnInt;

                case "G":

                    returnInt = 7;
                    return returnInt;

                case "H":

                    returnInt = 8;
                    return returnInt;

                case "I":

                    returnInt = 9;
                    return returnInt;

                case "J":

                    returnInt = 10;
                    return returnInt;

                case "K":

                    returnInt = 11;
                    return returnInt;

                case "L":

                    returnInt = 12;
                    return returnInt;

                case "M":

                    returnInt = 13;
                    return returnInt;

                case "N":

                    returnInt = 14;
                    return returnInt;

                case "O":

                    returnInt = 15;
                    return returnInt;

                case "P":

                    returnInt = 16;
                    return returnInt;

                case "Q":

                    returnInt = 17;
                    return returnInt;

                case "R":

                    returnInt = 18;
                    return returnInt;

                case "S":

                    returnInt = 19;
                    return returnInt;

                case "T":

                    returnInt = 20;
                    return returnInt;

                case "U":

                    returnInt = 21;
                    return returnInt;

                case "V":

                    returnInt = 22;
                    return returnInt;

                case "W":

                    returnInt = 23;
                    return returnInt;

                case "X":

                    returnInt = 24;
                    return returnInt;

                case "Y":

                    returnInt = 25;
                    return returnInt;

                case "Z":

                    returnInt = 26;
                    return returnInt;

                case "1":

                    returnInt = 27;
                    return returnInt;

                case "2":

                    returnInt = 28;
                    return returnInt;

                case "3":

                    returnInt = 29;
                    return returnInt;

                case "4":

                    returnInt = 30;
                    return returnInt;

                case "5":

                    returnInt = 31;
                    return returnInt;

                case "6":

                    returnInt = 32;
                    return returnInt;

                case "7":

                    returnInt = 33;
                    return returnInt;

                case "8":

                    returnInt = 34;
                    return returnInt;

                case "9":

                    returnInt = 35;
                    return returnInt;

                case "0":

                    returnInt = 36;
                    return returnInt;

                case " ":
                    returnInt = 37;
                    return returnInt;

                default:

                    subString = " ";
                    return 0;        
            }
        }

        //function to convrt back to string
        public static string ToText(int subInt)
        {
            string subString;

            // number to string conversion swith
            switch (subInt)
            {
                case 1:

                    subString = "A";
                    return subString;

                case 2:

                    subString = "B";
                    return subString;

                case 3:

                    subString = "C";
                    return subString;

                case 4:

                    subString = "D";
                    return subString;

                case 5:

                    subString = "E";
                    return subString;

                case 6:

                    subString = "F";
                    return subString;

                case 7:

                    subString = "G";
                    return subString;

                case 8:

                    subString = "H";
                    return subString;

                case 9:

                    subString = "I";
                    return subString;

                case 10:

                    subString = "J";
                    return subString;

                case 11:

                    subString = "K";
                    return subString;

                case 12:

                    subString = "L";
                    return subString;

                case 13:

                    subString = "M";
                    return subString;

                case 14:

                    subString = "N";
                    return subString;

                case 15:

                    subString = "O";
                    return subString;

                case 16:

                    subString = "P";
                    return subString;

                case 17:

                    subString = "Q";
                    return subString;

                case 18:

                    subString = "R";
                    return subString;

                case 19:

                    subString = "S";
                    return subString;

                case 20:

                    subString = "T";
                    return subString;

                case 21:

                    subString = "U";
                    return subString;

                case 22:

                    subString = "V";
                    return subString;

                case 23:

                    subString = "W";
                    return subString;

                case 24:

                    subString = "X";
                    return subString;

                case 25:

                    subString = "W";
                    return subString;

                case 26:

                    subString = "Z";
                    return subString;

                case 27:

                    subString = "1";
                    return subString;

                case 28:

                    subString = "2";
                    return subString;

                case 29:

                    subString = "3";
                    return subString;

                case 30:

                    subString = "4";
                    return subString;

                case 31:

                    subString = "5";
                    return subString;

                case 32:

                    subString = "6";
                    return subString;

                case 33:

                    subString = "7";
                    return subString;

                case 34:

                    subString = "8";
                    return subString;

                case 35:

                    subString = "9";
                    return subString;

                case 36:

                    subString = "0";
                    return subString;

                case 37:
                    subString = " ";
                    return subString;

                default:

                    subString = " ";
                    return subString;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // my variubles
            string message;
            string encMessage = "";
            int encKey;
            int keyCount = 0;
            int tempInt;
            string userChoice;

            //get user choice
            Console.WriteLine("Press [1] to Encrypt a message\n"
                              + "Press [2] to Decrypt a message");
            userChoice = Console.ReadLine();

            //ask user for message
            Console.WriteLine("Plaeas enter the message");
            message = Console.ReadLine();

            // make array of ints and strings
            int[] messageInt = new int[message.Length];
            string[] messageString = new string[message.Length];

            //ask user for Key
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter Eyncrytion Key");
            encKey = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            //start for loop to brake up message into ints
            for (int i = 0; i <= message.Length; i++)
            {
                //set message to numbers
                //THIS IS AS FAR AS THE PROGRAM QILL GET
                tempInt = ToNumber(message.Substring(i, i));

                // create array of chars
                messageInt[i] = tempInt;

            }

            //loop to change numbers back to strings
            for (int i = 0; i <= message.Length; i++)
            {
                // changenumber of message String array to ecnipt the message
                messageInt[i] = messageInt[i] + ToNumber(encKey.ToString().Substring(keyCount, keyCount));

                if (messageInt[i] > 37)
                {
                    messageInt[i] = messageInt[i] - 37;
                }

                //use ToString function to chage number back to enyncripted letter
                messageString[i] = ToText(messageInt[i]);

                // if else statment used to set part of ecnKey that is used
                if (keyCount < encKey.ToString().Length)
                {
                    keyCount++;
                }
                else
                {
                    keyCount = 0;
                }
            }

            // combine string array to make ecnipted message
            for (int i = 0; i <= message.Length; i++)
            {
                encMessage = encMessage + messageString[i];
            }

            Console.WriteLine(encMessage);


            //pause App
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the error:

```
int[] messageInt = new int[message.Length];
...
for (int i = 0; i <= message.Length; i++)
```

Since Indexes are 0 based, the largest element in the array won't have the index `of the message.Length` but rather of `message.Length - 1`. To fix this, simply replace this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= message.Length; i++)
```

with this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < message.Length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this

```
        static List<string> convertArray = new List<string>() { "START", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", " " };
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
        public static int ToNumber(string subString)
        {
            int results = convertArray.IndexOf(subString);
            if (results == -1) results = 0;
            return results;
        }
        public static string ToText(int subInt)
        {
            string results = " ";
            if (subInt > 0 && subInt < convertArray.Count())
            {
                results = convertArray[subInt];
            }
            return results;
        }
```